# Why is the dtype: object when all columns are float64 and int64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object

```py
print(cleaned_train.dtypes) 

print("--")

print(cleaned_test.dtypes)
```

```py
YearOfObservation       int64

Insured_Period        float64

Residential             int64

Building_Painted      float64

Building_Fenced       float64

Building_Type         float64

Claim                 float64

Building Dimension    float64

Geo_Code              float64

dtype: object

--

YearOfObservation       int64

Insured_Period        float64

Residential             int64

Building_Painted      float64

Building_Fenced       float64

Building_Type         float64

Claim                 float64

Building Dimension    float64

Geo_Code              float64

dtype: object
```

Tried getting a dtype:numeric but got object

Answer (score 1):

`dtype: object` is the dtype of the series returned by the dataframe's `dtypes` property, not the dtype of any column of the dataframe itself.

The elements of this series are dtype objects, not numbers, so the dtype of the series cannot be a numeric dtype.